# Subscribe to Spotify events

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotify

Does anyone know of a way to subscribe to events in the Spotify application? To subscribe to iTunes events, you would just add an observer to the notification center like this:

`[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changedTrack:) name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo" object:nil];`

Thereby all events will be send in an `NSNotification` to `changedTrack:`.

I can't seem to find a similar (or any way) to do this for Spotify but I know there are applications doing this, for example applications showing the song currently being played.

Comment: Do you know (or even suspect) that Spotify events use distrbuted notifications? If so, just fire up https://github.com/kballard/NotificationWatcher and see what they are. If it's doing something else… have you looked for a Spotify API or anything?

Comment: I didn't know about that application. I will definitely try it out. I looked at the Spotify API but it seemed to only allow communication with their servers. That's not really what I wanted.

Comment: It's really easy to explore other apps' distributed notifications if you don't know what they're sending—just add an observer with no filters on it. (Look at the source to NotificationWatcher if that isn't clear.) So, next time you run into something like this, you can figure it out faster than you can ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spotify's `NSDistributedNotification` name is `com.spotify.client.PlaybackStateChanged`.

Subscribe to that using `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` and you'll get a notification very similar to iTunes'.